# How to perform the action events in php for the image buttons

Tags: php

I have created one textfield and one dropdownlist and a Imagebutton in my "index.php" page as follows:

```
    <form value="indexform" action="" method="post">
    <b>Number:</b><input type="text" name="number"/><br/>
    <b>Network:</b>
    <select name="network">
    <option selected="">please...</option>
    <option value="1">Bsnl</option>
    <option value="2">Idea</option>
    </select>
    <input type="image" src="../ad.png" name="proceed" value="submit">
    </form>
```

and i have used the php code as follows for the above form:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['network']) && isset($_POST['number']))
    {
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $network = $_POST['network'];
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['network']))
    {
    switch($network)
    {
    case "1":header("Location:Bsnl.php");break;
    case "2":header("Location:Idea.php");break;
    default:exit();
    }
    ?>
```

and i have crated two pages "Bsnl.php" and "Idea.php" Based on the selection taken in the dropdownlist the page will be redirected into either Bsnl/Idea.php

I want to validate the form in index page after clicking that image button so i want code for action to be performed by that image button such that after validating that fields then it will be redirects into relevant page: can any one help me??

Comment: Unless the PHP is called index.php, the form won't submit to the correct location. Please change action as @KyleK suggested.

Comment: dude if the file name is placed in the action attribute it will redirects into that file only but my question is i want to redirect the page based on the field selected either bsnl/idea which the user select..based that selection only the page wants to redirect

Comment: Yeah, you name that second file something else....like Process.php, then put action="process.php" in the action attribute....then when it submits, it goes through the middle step of process.php, which redirects it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

This is validation but there is no number validation because you are not using number at all.

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['network']) && isset($_POST['number']))
    {
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $network = $_POST['network'];
    }
    if($network=="1"){
      header("Location:Bsnl.php");
    }elseif($network=="2"){
        header("Location:Idea.php");
    }
    exit();
    ?>
```

Comment: uh, he has a switch statement....how is this any different? Also... I think you misunderstood his problem.  Its actually simple...he just doesn't have anything in his action="" attribute, and was confused on how to get to that second processing page.

Comment: may be he want like, function f(){val = document.getElementById("network").value;if(val==1){document.indexform.action="bsnl.php";//form.submit();}else{document.indexform.action="idea.php";//form.submit();}}something like this. it's tough to write comment so i write short unclear answer

Answer (score 0):

This is your first **index.php**, notice the action now going to process.php...

```
<form value="indexform" action="process.php" method="post">
<b>Number:</b><input type="text" name="number"/><br/>
<b>Network:</b>
<select name="network">
<option selected="">please...</option>
<option value="1">Bsnl</option>
<option value="2">Idea</option>
</select>
<input type="image" src="../ad.png" name="proceed" value="submit">
</form>
```

Then this is your **process.php** which will redirect to Bsn1.php and Idea.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['network']) && isset($_POST['number']))
{
$number = $_POST['number'];
$network = $_POST['network'];
}
if(!empty($_POST['network']))
{
switch($network)
{
case "1":header("Location:Bsnl.php");break;
case "2":header("Location:Idea.php");break;
default:exit();
}
?>
```

And then based on your last question which was the same app, and I answered, you will switch those to Sessions to have them available across pages.
But I wont include that here, just refer to your last question...